# Android Studio - I opened a project, but I can't run anything. I only see 'Add Configuration...'

Tags: android-studio

Sorry, I don't have much Android Studio experience. I once opened a project (Oculus OpenXR Mobile SDK) in Android studio and got it to a point where I can run different apps in the project. Recently I had to open a fresh project of the same SDK, but now I only see 'Add Configuration...' instead of being able to run anything. Can someone help me please?

I tried 'Build-Make Project', but the 'Make Project' option is greyed out.

When I try 'Run-Run', I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Each request requires the same not null build mode to be set
```

[image]